# How does tf.train.batch create a batch

Tags: tensorflow

In the CIFAR-10 TensorFlow tutorial I encountered the following line:

```
images, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
        [image, label],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
        capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size)
```

The function `tf.train.batch()` seems to be taking as an input only one image and one label. How does it then create a batch with multiple images?

Answer (score 7):

It takes in input the pair `[image, label]` that, yes, it's a single pair. `tf.train.batch`, however, creates a queue internally. The `num_threads` threads will accumulate the pairs into the queue until `capacity` is reached.

The `images, label_batch` are, in fact, dequeue operations.

Remember that you're defining a computational graph, therefore the pair `[image, label]` represent two nodes of the graph and the the various *real* pair of `image, label` of your training set, will flow through these nodes. In this way, the `tf.train.batch` can capture the flow of the images and labels and fill the queue.

Comment: How can I print the current images that are being dequed for training ? I am using slim.learning.train in form similar to given here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/slim_walkthough.ipynb